# using hidden form field to reduce spam

Tags: php, forms

In  an effort to reduce spam i have a form with a value 'email2' that's hidden in CSS.

and then in my php processing form thing ive got this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['email2'])) 
{ die ("Sorry I believe you are a robot, please try again 
        and if you aren't... only enter your email once");
}
else {
submit data to mysql
}
```

The principle is that if the email2 form is left blank, which will happen with a human using css, the form will be processed. And then if it is filled by a bot filling everything in site then it will not be processed. And this is actually working BUT...

i dont understand how its working and i feel incredibly stupid. Correct me if i am wrong but looking at the code above it says if the email2 box is empty then the form is not processed. But in actuality it processes it if it's filled.

I am a mightily confused php amateur

Comment: There is an explanation mark right in front of `empty`, it's a boolean `NOT`

Comment: hang on, exclammation marks reverse the value dont they...oops. edit: you posted a comment as i was typing. Thank you! I feel stupid.

Comment: do i need to put email2 into the mysql escape variables and values and insertion bit and create space in my mysql table or can i leave all that out?

Comment: ! in front of the boolean statement makes it opposite meaning: !TRUE = FALSE, !FALSE = TRUE

Comment: @user3894741 — Are you putting email2 in your database? Since you are aborting the script if it is present: no.

Comment: not putting email2 in my database so i guess those steps are not needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!` is [the not operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

So it says if **not** empty.

Comment: this better be comment not answer :p

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili — It is an answer. It is a short answer, but that is because it is for a simple question.